# How can I check whether it is registered or not registered on firebase on the Login page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

```
   onPressed: () {
                      FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .authStateChanges()
                          .listen((User? user) {
                        if (user == null ||
                            _emailController.value.text.isEmpty ||
                            _passwordController.value.text.isEmpty) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              const SnackBar(
                                  content: SizedBox(
                                    height: 17.0,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Eksik veya yanlış giriş bilgileri",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                  margin:
                                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 10, 200, 50)));
                        } else {
                          FirebaseAuth.instance
                              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: _emailController.text,
                                  password: _passwordController.text)
                              .then((value) {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()));
                          });
                        }
                      });
```

I have defined 2 mails and passwords in Firebase. If the user enters with one of these e-mail and passwords, he will be able to log in. But when trying to login with an account not registered in firebase or leave required fields blank, a snackbar message will be shown.

I am able to show this snackbar message if it leaves the fields blank. I can also log in with the email and password I saved in Firebase. But if the e-mail and password entered by the user are not correct, I cannot show a snackbar message. If the input is correct, I added the step to the else loop, but I didn't understand how to add code inside the if loop.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to [authStateChanges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#authstatecha):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Comment: I updated my code. When I try to log in with an e-mail or password that is not registered in Firebase, snackbar appears now, thanks, but when I try to log in with the mail and password registered in Firebase, snackbar appears and does not go to the relevant page.

Comment: I don't think you should have a listener in onPressed. There you can use FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser to check the current user.